# How do I redirect an old Netlify + Jekyll site address, to the new address?

Tags: jekyll, netlify

I created a Jekyll site, hosted at Netlify, at `old.address.com`. Now I want to redirect to `new.address.com`. But the Netlify docs doesn't seem to work or I don't understand the docs. This is what I did:

I added, to `_config.yml`: (because Netlify says Jekyll excludes '_...' files)

```
include:
  - _redirects
```

And I added a `_redirects` file. I just copy-pasted Netlify's generated instructions into that file, this is the content:

```
# Redirect domain aliases to primary domain
https://jekyll-comments.demo.ed.community/* https://jekyll-demo.talkyard.io/:splat 301!
http://jekyll-comments.demo.ed.community/* https://jekyll-demo.talkyard.io/:splat 301!
https://jekyll.demo.talkyard.io/* https://jekyll-demo.talkyard.io/:splat 301!
http://jekyll.demo.talkyard.io/* https://jekyll-demo.talkyard.io/:splat 301!
```

And this has no effect. **What's the problem / what am I doing wrong?**

This is how the directory looks like:

```
$ ls -1
404.html
about.md
_config.yml
Gemfile
_includes
index.md
_layouts
_posts
_redirects     <—— added as per Netlify's instructions
_sass
_site

$ ls -1 _posts/
2018-01-01-like-about-jekyll.markdown
2018-01-02-installation-instructions.markdown
2018-01-02-kind-creatures.markdown
```

The config file is just the default one:

```
title: ...
email: ...
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: ...
github_username:  ...

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed

talkyard_comments_server_url: ...

include:
  - _redirects
```

Please note that although there are fairly many details above, *it's all just various default stuff*. So it's not specific to my problem. It should apply to all new Jekyll sites.

Comment: What is the content of `_redirects`?

Comment: @marcanuy It's the 2nd topmost code snippet above, the one that starts with `# Redirect domain aliases ...` (I edited the question to make this a bit more clear).

Comment: **CAUTION:** `include: ["_redirects"]` will override default setting `include: [".htaccess"]`. To ensure that `.htaccess` is also included in a Jekyll build, use `include: [".htaccess", "_redirects"]`

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer:  I work for Netlify

We have a specific section on this in our documentation: https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#handling-hostnames-and-protocols-differently

...and your snippet should work since it follows those conventions.

The only prerequisites to make that work are:

1) that you have your site configured in our UI to answer to ALL of those names - so:

```
jekyll-comments.demo.ed.community
jekyll-demo.talkyard.io
jekyll.demo.talkyard.io
```

2) and that all names are set up the same in DNS (CNAME to yournetlifysitename.netlify.com)

The only way to add "extra" names to your Netlify configuration is as domain aliases, which are configured in the Domain settings panel right next to your "main" custom domain.

Since your _redirects looks correct to me, if you have the prerequisites configured as suggested, the most likely failure mode is that you don't end up with your redirects actually applied for some reason (usually - they didn't get deployed because they didn't exist in a file called _redirects, in your publish folder, after the build), but your `include` in the jekyll config should allow that file to persist in that location.  That jekyll config is the "right" way to do it but for other site generators, we sometimes advise people to copy the redirects into place after build:  `jekyll build && cp netlify_redirects.txt _site/_redirects`

You can download whatever files are in your deploy to examine their "final state" via this tiny icon from any successful deploy logs page:

[image: deploy logs and icon example]

From a quick look at your site configuration, they appear to be deployed and working:

```
$ curl -v https://jekyll-comments.demo.ed.community/ -o /dev/null
* Connected to jekyll-comments.demo.ed.community (35.199.180.1) port 443 (#0)
[...]
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
[...]
< Location: https://jekyll-demo.talkyard.io/
```

So I guess the next question is...how are you testing?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. Yes indeed, `jekyll-comments.demo.ed.community` is properly redirected (I didn't notice before). But `https://jekyll.demo.talkyard.io/` is not. Both in the browser, and with cURL, `jekyll-comments.demo.ed.community` gets redirected. But `https://jekyll.demo.talkyard.io/` results in status 200 OK. I'm wondering if maybe there's some bug in the redirects code, if the target site is on the same 2nd level domain? `jekyll.demo.talkyard.io` and `jekyll-demo.talkyard.io` are both on `talkyard.io`.

Comment: I changed the `_redirects` file contents so `jekyll.demo` is status 301-redirected (instead of status 302). Didn't have any effect.  (I updated the question to show the new contents.)

Comment: Thanks for showing how I can download the content in the deployment folder. I didn't know about that.

Comment: Yup - I can see some buggy behavior there - I'll ping you in the helpdesk so we can try to track it down.  Essentially, your configuration is correct and strangely the http://jekyll.demo.talkyard.io redirect does work - but https doesn't.